# Angular 2 no unique component identifier generated for select arrow div

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to remove the arrow from an angular material select component.
To do that I have a custom CSS file where I say display: none.
Here is the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-remove-select-arrow

but as my CSS is custom for this component, I saw there's no unique identifier generated for the arrow div so CSS is not applied.

Can you please let me know what would be the best way to do achieve that?

Thanks for your help.
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you state the styles in a component's CSS file, custom attributes are added to it automatically, so that CSS is not applied outside of the current component. But that causes issues when you want to apply CSS to other components, in this case, `mat-select`.

There are two ways to solve this issue

1. Set `encapsulation` to none in component

   ```
   @Component({
       selector: 'select-form-example',
       templateUrl: 'select-form-example.html',
       styleUrls: ['select-form-example.css'],
       encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
   })
   export class SelectFormExample {

   }
   ```
2. Add the custom styles in `style.css` file instead of the component's CSS file
   `select-form-example.css`

I have updated the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-remove-select-arrow-syen9i?file=app%2Fselect-form-example.ts) with 1st step

Comment: Thanks. Doing that it will apply to all my other components but let's keep it simple for now. I'll see later if I want / need to create a custom components from this select without the arrow.

Comment: If you add a class similar to `custom-select` which i did in stackblitz demo on `mat-select` element in the html file, than it will not apply to all components as you would add that class only in case you want to hide the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Use `::ng-deep` in your case but note that this one is already deprecated.
Now your css rule becomes like this: `::ng-deep .staffing-cell .mat-select-arrow-wrapper`

Deprecation info: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Now for the "appropriate" way you need to leverage the material theming in which you can look up in their docs: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming